# How to change the FPGA supply voltage (VCCint and VCCBRAM) beyond recommended operating conditions on Vivado?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado, virtex-series-fpga

​

I am new to the field of FPGAs. The FPGA I am using is Virtex-7 VC707 -2 speed grade. In my research project, I am required to reduce the supply voltage (BRAM's specifically) to a low value, say 0.7 Volt. The board datasheet says that the supply voltage has a minimum and a maximum of -0.5 volts and 1.1 volts respectively but Vivado is not letting me alter the supply voltage beyond the recommended operating conditions (between 0.97 volts and 1.03 volts). How do I alter the supply voltage beyond the recommended operating conditions?

Thanks

Comment: The only reason Vivado allows you to specify a supply voltage is so that it can do its timing analysis correctly. Since the value you want is outside the operating range of the device, the tool does not support it. You're on your own!

Comment: @DaveTweed Looking in Vivado 2023.1 for a Kintex-7 the option to adjust the supply voltage only seems to be in the Reports -> Report Power -> Power Supply tab which looks to feed into how Vivado estimates the power consumption of the design, rather than for the timing analysis. Found via [63017 - Vivado Power Analysis - How do I set power supply voltages (worse-case or upper power supply voltage per rail)?](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/63017?language=en_US). I'm curious if you have a pointer to some documentation which shows how selecting the supply voltage affects the timing analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The FPGA I am using is Virtex-7 VC707 -2 speed grade

However, `VC707` isn't the part number of a Virtex-7 but rather an evaluation kit - [AMD Virtex 7 FPGA VC707 Evaluation Kit](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/ek-v7-vc707-g.html). The FPGA on the VC707 evaluation kit is [XC7VX485T-2FFG1761C](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Xilinx/XC7VX485T-2FFG1761C?qs=rrS6PyfT74ctuIReMVDPZw%3D%3D)

> but Vivado is not letting me alter the supply voltage beyond the recommended operating conditions (between 0.97 volts and 1.03 volts).

I'm not aware that Vivado allows the supply voltage to be adjusted, since VCCBRAM is provided by an external regulator external to the FPGA (and which can vary from board to board).

The [VC707 Evaluation Board for the Virtex-7 FPGA User Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documents/boards_and_kits/vc707/ug885_VC707_Eval_Bd.pdf) *Figure 1-33* shows VCCBRAM is generated by `U62` on the board:

[image]

And *Table 1-32:* shows VCC_BRAM is controlled by a UCD9248 PMBus Controller:

[image]

The VC707 user manual contains the following about using the PMBus on the VC707:

> The PMBus connector, J5, is provided for use with the TI USB Interface Adapter PMBus pod (TI part number EVM USB-TO-GPIO), which can be ordered from the TI website [Ref 25], and the associated TI Fusion Digital Power Designer GUI (downloadable from [Ref 25]). This is the simplest and most convenient way to **monitor the voltage and current values** for the power rail listed
> in Table 1-30, Table 1-31, and Table 1-32.

From looking at the VC707 schematic the PMBus signals are also connected to the Virtex-7, so logic in the FPGA could also access the PMBus.

> How do I alter the supply voltage beyond the recommended operating conditions?

While the VC707 user guide mentions using PMBus to *monitor* the voltage of the power rails, it could also potentially be used to adjust the VCCBRAM voltage. The [UCD9248](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucd9248.pdf) used on the VC707 have an Arm-7 core, so you would need to check if as-delivered UCD9248 program supports adjusting the VCCBRAM rail via a PMBus command or not.

> I am required to reduce the supply voltage (BRAM's specifically) to a low value, say **0.7** Volt.

What is the reason for reducing VCCBRAM to 0.7 V? That is below the *PG On Threshold (V)* of 0.9 V shown in *Table 1-32* of the VC707 user guide. *Power Good* is normally used to sequence power-up of multiple rails. If you need to reduce the VCCBRAM below the *PG On Threshold (V)* you would need to make more changes to change the *PG On Threshold (V)*.

Power good sequencing is normally used to allow the board to power up correctly, and if modify that could potentially damage the board or FGPA.

So, **why** do you have a requirement to operate the BRAM beyond the recommended limits?

Is that for some security research?

Comment: Hey Chester,

So I bought the TI adapter and used the corresponding TI software. What you are saying is correct - Power Good On voltage is 0.9 V. I tried to change the voltage by using arrow marks beside the voltage value. Kindly confirm if this is the way I change the voltage - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIE1W8pduwaItJNjfwWyLqISrBlKBpIC/view?usp=sharing .

I plan to generate errors in values stored in the BRAM randomly. For this, I want to perform a read operation at a reduced voltage, to wipe out some values, and then, perform a regular read operation to calculate the error rate.

Comment: @afterlifeswag04 Setting the Vout for VCCBRAM to 0.7 V in the TI Fusion Digital Power Designer GUI, while leaving the _Synchronize margins/limits/PG to Vout_ ticked, should have the desired effect of changing the VCCBRAM rail to 0.7 V while still allowing Power Good to be set active. Since this will cause the Virtex-7 to be operated outside of the recommended operating conditions I can't guarantee that this won't damage the Virtex-7 or other parts of the VC707 board.

Comment: thank you for the information! There is something I would like to ask: when I try to alter the BRAM's voltage, voltages supplied to the array's peripherals like write driver, sense amplifier, encoder/decoder are also affected?

Comment: @afterlifeswag04 I can't seem to find any information about how Xilinx have implemented BRAM in terms of the voltages supplied to the array's peripherals. To answer that part of your query suggest you need to ask Xilinx. However (a) It could be Xilinx proprietary information they won't release (b) Since you are trying to operate BRAMs with a supply voltage outside of the published datasheet range they may chose to not supply the details.