# Does Vivado use the supply voltage to control the timing analysis results?

Tags: vivado, kintex-series-fpga

The question [How to change the FPGA supply voltage (VCCint and VCCBRAM) beyond recommended operating conditions on Vivado?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/689671/101063) has the following comment from [Dave Tweed](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11683/dave-tweed):

> The only reason Vivado allows you to specify a supply voltage is so that it can do its timing analysis correctly.

Searching the Xilinx site could only seem to references to the supply voltage set in the Vivado project affecting the power analysis, rather than timing analysis. E.g. the article [63017 - Vivado Power Analysis - How do I set power supply voltages (worse-case or upper power supply voltage per rail)?](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/63017?language=en_US)

To investigate the effect of changing the supply voltages used:

1. Vivado v.2022.1
2. A project for a Kintex-7 xc7k160tfbg676-2. Block RAM utilisation is 99.23 %.
3. Generate the bitstream in two copies of the project. The 1st left all supply voltages set at the defaults. In the 2nd edited a constraint file to increase Vccbram and Vccint from their default of 1.000 V to 1.030 V (maximum):

   ```
   set_operating_conditions -voltage {Vccbram 1.030}
   set_operating_conditions -voltage {Vccint 1.030}
   ```
4. Compared the Vivado reports for the two builds, in which the supply voltages differed.

There was no change to the contents of the `*timing_summary_routed.rpt` timing report between the two builds.

There were changes to the contents of the `*_power_routed.rpt` power analysis report between the two builds:

| Report table | Report field | Value with Vccbram and Vccint at default of 1.000 V | Value with Vccbram and Vccint at 1.030 V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Summary | Total On-Chip Power (W) | 2.193 | 2.241 |
| Summary | Dynamic (W) | 2.043 | 2.084 |
| Summary | Device Static (W) | 0.149 | 0.157 |
| Power Supply Summary | Vccint Dynamic (A) | 0.819 | 0.834 |
| Power Supply Summary | Vccint Static (A) | 0.056 | 0.061 |
| Power Supply Summary | Vccbram Dynamic (A) | 0.010 | 0.010 |
| Power Supply Summary | Vccbram Static (A) | 0.013 | 0.014 |

There is no difference to the *Vccbram Dynamic (A)* estimated current, which is probably due to the project not having setup *I/O nodes activity*.

The conclusion of the above is that in the Vivado project changing the Vccint and Vccbram supply voltages only affected by the power analysis, and not the the timing analysis.

My question is it expected that a FPGA synthesis tool such as Vivado will use the supply voltage to affect the timing analysis, or is the tool setup to only expected the worst-case timing across the allowed supply voltage range?